# why different filter results in Gallery? Getting unexpected returned information

Tags: powerapps

I am trying to show the contents of a specific SharePoint document library folder in a powerapps gallery.  I am using the filter function

Filter function against a SharePoint document library not returning all expected content of the filtered folder.

Filtering to Folder A returns both sub folders and files, filtering to folder B returns just subfolders.

Both folders A and B have sub folders AND files.  I do not believe it is a permissions issue as I am the owner/creator of both folders A and B and all the sub content

I have been trying to understand if the 2000 limit is @ play here but both folders only have around 10 sub-items and filter is delegable, so my understanding is that it should not be.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Returns both subfolders and files :- `Filter(Documents,'Folder path' = "Shared Documents/FolderA/")`

Returns just subfolders :- `Filter(Documents,'Folder path' = "Shared Documents/FolderB/")`

I am deliberately hardcoding the folder path for the moment to aid debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to replicate your scenario on one of my Test instance.
First Image shows 3 folders created under SharePoint and FolderA and FolderB have files under them but FolderC is empty.

[image]

Now without any filter powerapps shows all folders and file as you can see in below screenshot.

[image]

Now when I added simple filter as  `Filter(Documents,IsFolder=true)` I got expected result as below.
[image]

Now when I added simple filter as  `Filter(Documents,IsFolder=false)` I got only files and no folder. I believe this will help you proceed further. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking and posting.  I did have that thought too (and apologies I should have said in my original post)
Filter(Documents,'Folder path' = "Shared Documents/FolderA/", IsFolder=false) returns file contents of folder as you might expect but Filter(Documents,'Folder path' = "Shared Documents/FolderB/", IsFolder=false) does not despite the existance of file items in folder B

Interestingly in your screen shots you are getting 'errorDetails' being returned for the name field. I do not see that but I am using the web studio, not desktop.  What does the error message say in example?

Comment: Not error message rather warning, "Delegation warning.The highlighted part of this formula might not work correctly with column "IsFolder" on large data sets".

I believe there are 2 things happening here.
1. Your powerapp had cached data (guess) because on web version it does that all the time and refreshing entire app loads correct data.
2. how about you do not add Folder path rather let powerapp retrieve all the data from Documents .
3.(At first do not add any filter and see if you get files and folder both.
4. If you do get files and folder then go next step with simple filter.

Comment: all very wise words, and have been doing just that for the last 2 days or so....straight Gallery call returns both folders and files, simple filters such as isFolder=true/False works fine, but when you get to filter by specific folders some work and some dont.  I have noticed that folders with a space in the name e.g. "folder name" do not work but "foldername" does.  thinking it might be something to do with that. Also been playing with metadata (to make filter more precise) and that shows the same behaviour too.   very odd

Comment: ahh might be, I just tried with "Folder F Space" and this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

just created a new document library in the same parent sharepoint site and lo the filter is working correctly.

I wonder how long it will before the new folder breaks...